# WSO2 ESB: Moving a file from source path received in a web service payload

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I have a web service in WSO2 ESB that receives a file path. Everytime the service is consumed I have to move all files from the path received to another one.

I have beeing having a look to vfs but it is a daemon (obviously you can set the interval time to a very high value). I have done some proxies that move files from a path to another one, but I have no idea of how to do that on demand, and using at the same time a web service as trigger.

Can I do this using vfs+SoapWS?

Comment: I think you have to deal with custom mediator with parameters here if some non trivial logic is involved.

Comment: I think so. That is the conclusion I have reach after searching the Internet. My idea is to write a custom mediator using the library apache vfs just to copy on demand, with source and target path as parameters.